# Regex Dark Corners in Java... order of chars alters regex meaning?

Tags: java, regex

I recently came across some odd behavior that involves Java's regex engine.

When writing some validation, I needed to add square brackets to my regex, like so:

```
"[^a-zA-Z0-9_/.@ ]"  // original expression
"[^a-zA-Z0-9_/.@ /]/[]"  // first modificiation
```

However... this implementation failed.  After experimentation, I discovered that it would then work if I moved the space `char` to the end.

```
"[^a-zA-Z0-9_/.@/]/[ ]"  // final working modification
```

Now the calling code that used this expression used the `String.replaceAll(String, String)` method, as listed [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

My question is... does anyone have any good technical idea on why the placing of the space alters the meaning of this regex?  It really shouldn't matter.

[EDITED]
From the comments and answers--this is an example where using the built-in String method leads to incorrect behavior that is NOT caught.  My Runtime environment does NOT complain at all even though if you read the documentation on `String.replaceAll(String, String)` it clearly states that it is the same functionality as      `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)`  I think I will file a bug.

Comment: **How** did it fail? I guess you get a [`PatternSyntaxException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/PatternSyntaxException.html).

Comment: When you are writing `/]/[` do you want to include the square brackets in the character class? If so, you failed because of the wrong escape character and created a second one.

Comment: There was no compilation error.  It failed by not correctly catching the brackets.  I have since fixed my faulty syntax however.  Thanks!

Comment: @avgvstvs: the regex you labeled "first modification" **can't work**. It **must** throw a `PatternSyntaxException` when compiling/applying it. If you never saw that, then something in your code is swallowing that and you should fix it (because then your code silently fails, which is A Bad Thing™).

Comment: @Joachim, I checked for swallowed exceptions, the client code is set to catch/log based on Throwable.  NOTHING should get by that.  Now in the broader environment, it is included in a Grails project.  But that shouldn't affect the java code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the wrong escaping character, it's `\` and not `/`.

Also, I'm not sure if you wanted your character group to include `/` and `.` or if you thought that `.` needs to be escaped in character groups (it doesn't need to be escaped: it always represents the literal `.` in character groups).

When trying to compile `[^a-zA-Z0-9_/.@ /]/[]` it gives this exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 20
[^a-zA-Z0-9_/.@ /]/[]
                    ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2254)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1818)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
```

This indicates that there is a problem with the character class at that point. And in fact: you've got an empty character class `[]` which is not valid!

`[^a-zA-Z0-9_/.@ /]/[]` means "a character not matching (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, `_`, `/`, `.`, `@`,   or `/`), followed by a slash `/` followed by <fails to compile because it is malformed>".

What you want is probably `[^a-zA-Z0-9_.@ \]\[]` which is "a character not matching a-z, A-Z, 0-9, `_`, `.`, `@`, , `]` or `[`".

If you write it in a `String` literal remember to double the `\` (because they have special meanings in `String` literals as well!):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9_.@ \\]\\[]");
```

Comment: I altered my syntax, but I'm not getting an exception at all when I ran this my incorrect way.  (not joking.  It compiled and ran fine on my machine... has for the 6 weeks I've been working with it.)  And no...  there's no compiler silencing.

Comment: @avgvstvs: what happens if you put **just** `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9_/.@ /]/[]");` in a `main` method and execute that on your machine? Maybe you're using a different `Pattern` implementation that is more lenient.

Comment: THAT certainly fails, but not when using the `String.replaceAll(String, String)` method as in the OP.  I think this highlights an apparent imperfection in the implementation of `.replaceAll()`.

Comment: Interesting. On my machine that throws the same `PatternSyntaxException`, which isn't surprising as the OpenJDK implements `String.replaceAll()` using `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceAll(replacement)`.